# Level sets volume

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ is a nice function (whatever nice should mean), non-negative, with a compact support.
Fix $v >0$ and define
$$ A_{\epsilon} := \{x\in \mathbb{R}^d : v \le f(x) \le v+\epsilon\}.$$

I want to claim something like:
$$ \lim_{\epsilon  \to 0} \frac{Vol(A_{\epsilon})}{\epsilon}= h(v),$$
where $Vol(\cdot)$ is the Euclidean volume, and $h(v)$ is some function of $v$. In other words, I want to claim that the volume of $A_\epsilon$ scales like $\epsilon$.

I am not sure what is the right argument to invoke here, and what assumptions are needed on $f$. Will appreciate any help.

Thanks.